# Return a class that conforms to a swift protocol (the actual class, not an instance of it)

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm having trouble with returning a class instead of an instance of it which conforms to a protocol. Is that something that's possible to do? Here's an approximation of my code:

```
public protocol MyProt {
    //things
}

var protConformer: MyProt {
    return boolVar ? ClassOne : ClassTwo // where both classes conform to MyProt
}
```

Of course, I get an error here saying `"Cannot convert return expression of type 'ClassOne.Type' to return type 'MyProt'`. Any ideas on whether this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the type of `protConformer` to the meta type of the protocol, namely `MyProt.Type` if you want to return a *type* conforming to the protocol and not an instance of such a type.

```
var protConformer: MyProt.Type {
    return boolVar ? ClassOne.self : ClassTwo.self
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type MyProt means "an *instance* of a type that adopts MyProt." If you really mean to manipulate metatypes, the syntax is:

```
var protConformer: MyProt.Type {
    return boolVar ? ClassOne.self : ClassTwo.self
}
```

But I must warn you, this is almost never the right thing to do. You may be looking for a generic here (in whatever your real-life problem is).